# Array PHP en WHERE de consulta mysql

Tags: php, mysql, array

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
<?php
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM etapas_lab WHERE id_cliente = '$id_us'";                                                          
 $ejecutar_consulta = $conexion->query($consulta);
  $nomx = array();
    while ($registro = $ejecutar_consulta->fetch_assoc())                                    
    {
      $nom = utf8_encode($registro["nombre"]);
      echo '<th>'.$nom.' </th>';
    }
 ?>
```

Lo que necesito, es agregar una condicion dentro del WHERE de esa consulta, usando un array php, llamado $miarray que viene de otra consulta previa.
La idea de todo esto, es comparar los id que estan en ese array con los datos de la columna etapas (ver imagen adjunta) y mostrar el nombre del producto que corresponde.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien, tiene alguna idea, agradeceria me pudiesen orientar de como hacer eso.
Como siempre, agradecido de su ayuda.
Saludos a todos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En vez de crar un array, ya que van a ser solo un conjunto de id's, puedes generar un string de la siguiente forma:

```
function funcionSacaId(param){
    $consulta = //consulta para sacar las id's ;
    $result = $conexion->query($consulta);
    $ids = "";
    if($result){
       while($row=$result->fetch_array()){
       // Esto crea un string como 'id1','id2','id3',
           $ids .= "'".$row['id'] . "', ";
       }
       // Esto quita el ultimo espacio y coma del string generado con lo cual
       // el string queda 'id1','id2','id3'
       $ids = substr($ids,0,-2);
    return $ids;
    }
}
```

Y ya después en el código que has pasado sustituir la consulta:

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM etapas_lab WHERE id_cliente = '$id_us'";
```

por:

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM etapas_lab WHERE id_cliente in (".$id_us.")";
```

Espero que te sirva :)

Comment: Para agregar otra condición, si la consulta que saca esos valores te devuelven valores de  una sola columna tambien, puedes hacer el mismo proceso que el que he ejemplificado en la respuesta y a la consulta final añadirle : `AND id_etapas in (".$id_etapas.")` por ejemplo

Comment: Perfecto, claro como el agua. Me funciono de maravillas. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que una versión mejor que la que propone Enrique Manzano Gil, sería esta (no la he probado):

```
function funcionSacaId(param){
    $consulta = //consulta para sacar las id's ;
    $result = $conexion->query($consulta);

    if($result){

       while($row=$result->fetch_array()){
       // Utiliza implode para construir un string con el separador que necesites
           $ids = implode(",", $row['id']);
       }

       return $ids;
    }
}
```

La idea es cambiar el invento de construir un string concatenando para luego quitar la coma final que te daría error al ejecutar la query, y utilizar la función [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), que es para ese fin.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un ciclo para construir la consulta con los datos de tu array

```
//Generamos el inicio de la consulta
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM etapas_lab WHERE ";

// Agregamos los elementos a consultar
foreach ($miarray as $valor){
    $consulta .= "id_cliente = ".$valor." or ";
}

// Eliminamos el ultimo or
$consulta = substr($consulta,0,-3);
```

De esta forma puedes crear la parte de WHERE en tu consulta

Comment: hola Jose, gracias por tu respuesta, pero como agrego otra condicion?. tengo que agregar otra que seria WHERE id = '.$array.'.

Comment: Creo que la solución de Enrique es mejor

Answer (score 0):

Me sirvio la respuesta de Jose , solo falta definir el string vacio antes e irlo agregando a la sentencia de cada foreach.

El var_dump final lo eliminas pero te dara por consola una vista de como quedaria la consulta del condicional where.

```
// Definimos antes el string vacio

$where= "";

// Recorremos el array agregando el where condicional de cada id

foreach ($miarray as $valor){
    $where = $where . "id_cliente = ".$valor." or ";
}

// Eliminamos el ultimo or
$whereFormateado = substr($where,0,-3);

//Generamos la consulta final;
    $consultaFinal = "SELECT * FROM etapas_lab WHERE " . $whereFormateado;
    

var_dump ($consultaFinal);
```